Issues with CSS and Routing After Migrating from Create React App to Vite
I recently migrated my project from Create React App (CRA) to Vite for better performance and developer experience. While everything works perfectly fine locally during development, I encountered a couple of issues after building and serving the production build using npx serve dist
CSS for react-phone-input-2: After migrating to Vite, I noticed that certain styles for react-phone-input-2 are broken compared to the original styles. This discrepancy occurs only in the production build served via npx serve dist. Locally during development, the styles appear as expected. I suspect there might be a difference in how Vite handles CSS compared to CRA, but I'm unsure how to resolve this issue.
Routing Issues: In my application, I have routes like /login and /register, which are supposed to display login and registration pages respectively. Locally, when I navigate to these routes (e.g., http://localhost:3000/login), the pages load without any issues. However, in the production build served via npx serve dist, I encounter a 404 error when accessing these routes directly. Interestingly, navigating to the root URL (http://localhost:3000/) redirects me to the login page, as intended, and this functionality works as expected both locally and in production.
I'm seeking assistance to help me understand and resolve these issues. Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
